# Angular validation directive

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a lot of forms in my application, with different validation for every input.
I want to use a directive for all inputs to show the validation error message, and indicate the user that the input is not valid.

What is the best generic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a directive that watches `form.$error` and display all the errors.

```
return {
    require: '^form',
    templateUrl: '...',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngForm) {
        scope.$watch(
            function() { return ngForm.$error; },
            function(errors) {
                // for each error typ
                angular.forEach(errors, function(errorTypes, errorType) {
                    // for each error
                    angular.forEach(errorTypes, function(error) {
                        // handle the error

                    });
                });

        }, true);
    }
}
```

Use this directive once inside a form

```
<form novalidate>
  <my-validation></my-validation>
  <input ng-model="m" required>
</form>
```